# Show there does not exist a continuously differentiable function f on [0,2] such that f(0)=-1, f(2)=4 and f'(x)<=2 for 0<=x<=2

Tags: real-analysis

Show there does not exist a continuously differentiable function f on [0,2] such that f(0)=-1, f(2)=4, and f'(x)<=2 for 0<=x<=2

I am not sure how show this is the case using the fundamental theorem.

I know the formula for the Fundamental theorem of calculus:
so for this problem integral from 0 to 2 of f is 5.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Use the *Mean value theorem*.